# Keeping a strong pointer to a local object

Tags: ios, objective-c

I encountered this thing in a book which I am reading and it got me thinking:

"When you allocate a block, it is created on the stack. This means that, even if you were to keep a strong reference to it, calling it later would result in a crash because the memory would be destroyed as soon as you leave the method in which it was defined."

I thought if I *have a strong pointer* to something, it is *kept alive*?
Does this mean this does not apply for objects allocated on the stack?

I am trying to think of an example without using blocks...(e.g., of pointer - maybe an ivar- pointing to a stack allocated object which gets destroyed even though the pointer is alive)

Comment: This (almost) only applies to blocks. Don't worry, Objective-C objects are created on the heap and are retain counted just as usual.

Comment: @David Rönnqvist: yep, like I said I was trying to think of a example where a pointer is pointing to an object which was allocated on the stack... (though could not come up with one, maybe since I am not that experienced yet in iOS).

Comment: You don't alloc Objective-C objects on the stack.

Comment: @David Rönnqvist: I know but thought you could have something like: `ivarPointer = x;` where x is a local object, like int... you'd need to use & before it though then .. .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objects are never allocated on the stack in Objective-C. Blocks are special however, since they are stack allocated. So if you want to retain a pointer to a block, you must first copy it by using `Block_copy` and use the copy, then release it with `Block_release`. This must be done if the block is to be used after the scope it was declared in is destroyed. More on the matter here:  https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxUsing.html (under "Copying Blocks"). Yet again though, this does not apply to regular objects.

Comment: why not: e.g., `int x = 12;` inside a method call would be stack allocated isn't it? Then I'd only have to point to it somehow...

Comment: `int` is not an object (in Objective-C terms). Objects are everything that can be assigned to `id`. `int`, `char`, `time_t`, `NSInteger` etc. are POD types that are inherited from C and follow C semantics.

Comment: I know I know, I just started wondering what would happen to such an "object" (e.g., POD) if it is stack allocated and if I have a strong pointer to it, would it still get destroyed? (that's what I meant in the end of my question)... maybe I said something stupid? because I am not very experienced iOS developer yet...

Comment: You can not have a strong pointer to a POD type. It will fail to compile. For example: `__strong int* p = &x` will not compile.

Comment: yep that's what I meant in my question, that I could not come up with the example... thanks anyway..

Comment: Actually one correction, it seems the compiler automatically does a copy of the block on the heap if it is not there; e.g., from the book: "So, even if you just assign a block to a strong variable or use a strong property, the block is copied to the heap for you if it is not already there.".

Comment: Just as a piece of advice - if you are declaring a block property, use `copy` instead of `strong`

Answer (score 1):

Blocks can be messaged like objects. To move them from the stack to the heap, just "copy" them.

```
void (^stackBlock)() = [^(){
    NSLog(@"Hello world");
} copy];
```